# Subscribe and Unsubscribe on Each Emitted Item

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I am using the [reactive-location](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation) lib.

My use case is that I have a stream of objects emitted from an observable. These items can be emitted potentially every few hours. As soon as an item is emitted I want to obtain a location and using zipWith(as far as I can understand) emit an object containing the location.

The problem is: as the objects will only be emitted once every few hours, I cannot keep the location observable hot as it would drain the battery.

So I need the following: once an object is passed into the stream, subscribe to the location observable once a location is obtained, unsubscribe to the location observable. This must be done continuously.

As far as I understand this transformer takes care of unsubscribing

```
public <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> takeNextAndUnsubscribe() {
    return new Observable.Transformer<T, T>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> tObservable) {
            final BehaviorSubject subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
            Observable source = tObservable.doOnNext(new Action1<T>() {
                @Override
                public void call(T t) {
                    subject.onNext(t);
                }
            });
            return Observable
                    .merge(source.takeUntil(subject), subject)
                    .take(1);
        }

    };
}
```

But how would I subscribe again once a new object is sent down the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is to combine the source items with the current location when they are emitted. No need for anything fancy here. Just use `flatMap()` on each of the source items to combine it with the location.

```
source.flatMap(item ->
        locationProvider
                .getLastKnownLocation()
                .map(location -> new ItemWithLocation<>(item, location))
);

class ItemWithLocation<T> {
    private final T item;
    private final Location location;

    public ItemWithLocation(T item, Location location) {
        this.item = item;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated with second example. The following will subscribe for location updates until a specific accuracy is reached and then combine it with your source item. The key here is the use of `first()`. Using it will unsubscribe from the location provider whenever you get a location that satisfies your needs.

```
LocationRequest request = 
        LocationRequest
            .create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(100);

source.flatMap(item ->
        locationProvider
                .getUpdatedLocation(request)
                .first(location -> location.getAccuracy() < 5.0f)
                .map(location -> new ItemWithLocation<>(item, location))
);
```

Comment: The issue is I want a new location, not the lastknown

Comment: What API are you using from reactive-location? It wasn't clear so I used `getLastKnownLocation()` in my example. I've updated the answer with a second example that shows how to handle unsubscribing from a non-terminating location Observable.